# Convert bit type to Yes or No by query Sql Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I Want convert `bit` type to *Yes or No*

***For Example:***

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, IsMale from members
```

***Results:***

```
Ramy    Said    1
```

***Expected Result:***

```
Ramy    Said    Yes
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can do this using a [searched case expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx):

```
SELECT
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    CASE WHEN IsMale = 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS IsMale
FROM
    Members
```

Comment: If IsMale  is NULL ?

Answer (score 6):

Here you go:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, CASE WHEN IsMale = 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS Male
FROM members
```

Basically, you use a `CASE` statement to allow you to convert the value.  If you had three choices, you could still use the case statement and just add another option (obviously you can't have three options with a bit but if the field was an int, etc.)  The `ELSE` statement is the default statement that runs if you don't get a match.  In our case, we just use it for No since we can only have yes or no but in the case of a larger `CASE` statement, you would want to use this as your fall-back field.  For example, you could say "Item Not Found" if you were converting items.

Answer (score 5):

Use a `CASE`;

```
SELECT 
  FirstName,
  LastName,
  CASE IsMale WHEN 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS IsMale
FROM tbl
```

Answer (score 3):

Use an `IIF()` which is available `SQL Server 2012` onwards.

There is one another way of achieving this. *(shorthand way(maybe not))*. That's using `IIF()`. See below.

```
SELECT
  [FirstName],
  [LastName],
  IIF([IsMale]=1,'Yes','No') AS [IsMale As String] 
FROM 
  [Members]
```

Comment: The question is tagged SQL Server 2005, but the IIF function is only available from SQL Server 2012 onwards.

Comment: @jazza Thanks for the tip. I will update that in my answer. It will be helpful to someone in future.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2012 introduces two new keywords `FORMAT` and `IIF` that can provide a more compact means of converting an integer or bit to string:

```
DECLARE @MyInt int = 123
PRINT 'Hello '+FORMAT(@MyInt,'')

-- (note: the "+0" converts a bit type to int then outputs '0' or '1')
DECLARE @MyBit bit = 0
PRINT 'Hello '+FORMAT(@MyBit+0,'')
```

But to convert a `bit` type to `Yes` or `No` I would now use:

```
PRINT 'Hello '+IIF(@MyBit=1,'Yes','No')
```